# Converting TZ time to string

Tags: python, datetime

Pretty new to python and I'm even having difficulty searching for this on google since I don't know exactly what time format this is.

Time Format : `'2019-12-13T17:00:54.942Z'`

I tried the following :

```py
from datetime import datetime

'created_at': datetime.strptime(saved_data['created_at'],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Basically I want to print out a humanly readable string of the upper mentioned time format.

Thank you!

Comment: You want the result to have `'2019-12-13T17:00:54.942Z` format or is it the format of your input (i.e. `saved_data['created_at']`)? Plus, please share the format you find *human-readable*.

Comment: Hello I want "2019-12-13T17:00:54.942Z" to be readable eg. "2019-12-13 17:00:54" or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

datetime_obj = parser.parse(saved_data['created_at'])
readable = datetime.strftime(datetime_obj,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print (readable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input date format is in RFC 3339 format

Using `pyRFC3339` python module is the easiest way to parse/generate RFC3339 formatted timestamps to/from python datetime.datetime objects.

```
>>> import pyrfc3339
>>> ts='2019-12-13T17:00:54.942Z'
>>> new_ts = pyrfc3339.parse(ts)
>>> new_ts
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 13, 17, 0, 54, 942000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> print(new_ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
2019-12-13 17:00:54
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `datetime` has a method designed to do precisely this - `.isoformat()`.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = parser.parse(saved_data['created_at'])
data = {
    'created_at': datetime_object.isoformat()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've converted ISO8601 formatted string to a datetime object `datetime.strptime`, you can just:

1. Remove milliseconds by `.replace(microsecond=0)`
2. Stringify the result by `str(some_datetime_obj)`

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

some_iso8601_str = '2019-12-13T17:00:54.942Z'
datetime_str = str(datetime.strptime(some_iso8601_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').replace(microsecond=0))
print(datetime_str)
```